# Configuring Remote Desktop for Worker role in the new portal

Tags: azure

I am having a problem configuring the remote desktop connection in the new Windows Azure portal:

- Created a new worker role.
- Configured the remote desktop connection with an expiration time in the past.
- Exported and uploaded the generated certificate.
- Published the worker role.
- Configure the remote desktop in the new Windows Azure Portal (manage.windowsazure.com). This last step gives an error: "Remote Desktop cannot be enabled. The role definition does not contain the Remote Desktop module."

This is strange, because when I select the instance and try to connect, the rdp-file is downloaded and I can connect, ofcourse Windows won't let me, because the useraccount is disabled.
When I go to the previous portal, I can configure the connection.

Hopefully somebody can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Share your `CSDEF` file - to get RDP to work in the new portal, you must add `<Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />` and likely `<Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />` to your `CSDEF` imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the following in your .CSDEF file

```
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.Enabled" value="true" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountUsername" value="s093294" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword" value="{encoded password" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountExpiration" value="2014-05-01T23:59:59.0000000+02:00" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.Enabled" value="true" />
```

and in your .csdef file:

```
<Imports>
  <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
  <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
</Imports>
```

The easiest way to add it is from visual studio when packaging/deploying.

Comment: I already tried this in a small test project, there it is working. Adding it to my real project, the problem occurs

Comment: Have you added the modules before publishing the project to azure?

Comment: Have you payed attention to possible having both local and global config files?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem.

The worker role had spaces in it's name: "Application and Services"
Changed the name to "ApplicationAndServices".
Now it is working.